# Count query results on multi-join statements

Tags: sql

```
select cnt.loginid, grp.last_name as 'Group Name' 
from contact cnt 
    right join grpmem list on cnt.contact_uuid = list.member 
    left join contact grp on grp.contact_uuid = list.group_id 
    join contact_acctyp cntacc on cnt.contact_uuid = cntacc.contact_uuid
where cntacc.c_acctyp_id in (select id from acctyp_v2 where sym like 'CDN%')
```

I have written a query for our system that pulls a list of all Canadian contacts and the group they are in.

Now, for people who are in multiple groups (their loginid appears multiple times) I need to determine the number of groups they are in (return a count).  However, I am unsure of how to perform the count.

I'd like my output to be in the following format:

```
| USER ID | # of Groups |
```

I can't seem to figure out how to turn what I've written into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all you want to do is aggregate the information you are already getting back, and without looking in detail at your query, here is a guess:

```
select 
    cnt.loginid, 
    COUNT(*)
from contact cnt 
    right join grpmem list on cnt.contact_uuid = list.member 
    left join contact grp on grp.contact_uuid = list.group_id 
    join contact_acctyp cntacc on cnt.contact_uuid = cntacc.contact_uuid
where cntacc.c_acctyp_id in (select id from acctyp_v2 where sym like 'CDN%')
GROUP BY
     cnt.loginid
```

Comment: So far so good. Now I just need a way to list where count(*) > 1

Comment: simply add: 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1