# How can I display the output of a query along with the amount of results in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to output a list of records in my database along with how many records there is.

For example, this would give me the output of my query;

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE [Condition];
```

But then I would also like to have amount of records displayed that come from the query. Is there anyway to include the

```
SELECT count(*) FROM TableName
```

In the same request?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You want to have the count in a additional column in the first query, or in an additional row?

Comment: Just add `count(*)` after '*' in the first query.

Comment: you didn't search about how to you get query result count through php or mysql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count query results on multi-join statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105053/count-query-results-on-multi-join-statements)

Answer (score 0):

I've done it.
Thank you guys! Upon realisation of how simple it is, I feel dumb!

```
SELECT *, count(*) FROM Table 
[Condition];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT *, count(*) AS count FROM TableName
WHERE [Condition];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do:

```
SELECT *, count(*) FROM TableName
WHERE [Condition];
```

Then you are actually grouping the result. What you can do is:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.cnt FROM TableName t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT count(*) cnt FROM TableName) t2
WHERE [Condition];
```

Comment: For me that doesnt work. If I run the first query, i get the first row of the table plus the count of the table. I dont receive all rows from the table.